# convert table to data frame with the first column as a variable - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table object in R. It looks a bit like this:

```
           2422 2581 3363
  16566    0    1    0
  16568    0    2    0
  16598    0    1    0
  16627    0    1    0
  16683    0    1    0
  16701    0    1    0
  16740    0    1    0
  16741    0    1    0
```

I'd like to convert it to a data frame, whereby this data frame should have **4** variables, not 3. In other words, the first column, `16566, 16568,` etc. should be a variable - let's call it ID. The other variables should be the `2422, 2581, 3363` columns.

I've tried 
`as.data.frame()`  and 
`as.data.frame.matrix()`
but both functions somehow swallow the first column.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df <- as.data.frame(table)
df$ID <- rownames(table)
```